# How do I configure jEdit for Scala projects?

Tags: ide, scala, editor, jedit

I'd like to be able to use jEdit to write, compile and test projects written in Scala. How can I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new link appears to be http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php?title=SetUp_jEdit

Answer (score 4):

May be this <del>[JEdit Setup with Scala](http://liftweb.net/index.php/SetUp_jEdit)</del> [**setup jEdit to develop Scala**](http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php?title=SetUp_jEdit) can help you ?
(new updated link, as mentioned by [David Vydra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83395/david-vydra) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428819/how-do-i-configure-jedit-for-scala-projects/687984#687984))

It refers to a [JEdit fully configured](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/alchim/ScalaMiniIDEPlugin-0.3.1-full.zip?use_mirror=osdn) to run Scala projects.

http://wiki.liftweb.net/images/9/91/Screenshot-jedit.png

Answer (score 0):

I literally just use the jEdit mode (my [tweaked version](http://github.com/djspiewak/jedit-modes/tree/master/scala.xml)) and leave it at that.  All of my compilation, shell and SCM stuff is done in a separate Terminal window.  Often times I will use "Project Viewer" to manage things at a project level, but that's just because I'm too lazy to type in a new path every time I have to Cmd+O.

jEdit + Buildr + JavaRebel (for the shell) == an excellent workflow.  I don't get the compile-on-save behavior offered by the Scala Plugin, but I can live without that.  Compiling Scala on save is tricky anyway due to the complexity of the type system.